# custom style for just the first row of the table view

Tags: ios, ruby, uitableview, rubymotion

I am trying to set a different style for the first row of my table view.

I'm doing this by the following code:

```
def tableView(table_view, cellForRowAtIndexPath: index_path)
  data_row = @data[index_path.row]
  puts index_path.row
  if index_path.row == 0
    cell = table_view.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ITEM_CELL_ID) || begin
      rmq.create(ItemCell, :first_cell, reuse_identifier: ITEM_CELL_ID).get
    end
  else
    cell = table_view.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ITEM_CELL_ID) || begin
      rmq.create(ItemCell, :rest_cell, reuse_identifier: ITEM_CELL_ID).get
    end
  end
  cell.update(data_row)
  cell
end
```

**Question**

However I get very weird behavior with this. The first row does have the custom styling....but so does the 10th and 20th row!! I don't know why that would happen. Rows 2 - 9 and 11-19 are different than row 0 and 10 and 20.

Comment: what is that `puts index_path.row` returning?

Comment: it is returning `0, 1, 2, 3...10...15...20..` etc. I even tried puts index_path.class.to_s and that returns `Fixnum`

Comment: shot in the dark, but what if you try `if index_path.row/2 == 0` - might work, might not, but if it doesn't then you'll know for sure that it's not the number comparison causing it

Comment: that doesn't work either. I think the issue with with iOS painting only a few rows to begin with and then repainting them on the screen on scroll or something. so weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use different `ITEM_CELL_ID` (reuseIdentifiers) for each cell type. So the `:first_cell` styled cell should have a different `reuseIdentifier` constant than the `:rest_cell` styled cells. That should fix your issue since what you're seeing is that first cell's memory being reused over and over again as the table scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how your method is being called, so maybe this isn't possible...but, I imagine this is being called from a collection (or that there is a collection involved somewhere along the stack).  could you do something like this:

```
#wherever you're calling this from 
index_paths.each_with_index do |path, i| #add an 'index path'
  tableView(table_view,  cellForRowAtIndexPath: path, i)
  ...
end

#updated original method
def tableView(table_view, cellForRowAtIndexPath: index_path, path_index) #add path index
  data_row = @data[index_path.row]
  puts index_path.row
  if path_index == 0 #add path index
    cell = table_view.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ITEM_CELL_ID) || begin
      rmq.create(ItemCell, :first_cell, reuse_identifier: ITEM_CELL_ID).get
    end
  else
    cell = table_view.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ITEM_CELL_ID) || begin
      rmq.create(ItemCell, :rest_cell, reuse_identifier: ITEM_CELL_ID).get
    end
  end
  cell.update(data_row)
  cell
end
```